# Is it dangerous for all 14ga wiring in my house to be protected by 20A breakers?

Tags: wiring

Why hasn't my house burned down?
I just moved into a rental and upon inspecting the wiring to make sure I can run my woodshop safely I found all through the house 14 awg is on 20 amp breakers. Even the washer and gas dryer are using the same recepticle. I know none of this is legit nec code but more over why hasn't a fire started yet. Also no breakers are tripping and house was built in 79

Comment: Because you're lucky? Not sure what kind of an answer you expect here. Unsafe wiring is a fire risk, not a fire guarantee.

Comment: Because 14 gauge 90 degree THHN copper can take 25 amps "in Raceway, Cable or Earth.  Based on
Ambient Temperature of 30°C (86°)". You're required to protect it with a 15 amp breaker because (the NEC says so) "The allowable values in the [Ampacity Table](https://www.usawire-cable.com/pdfs/nec%20ampacities.pdf) are *based on temperature alone* and do not take voltage drop into consideration."

Comment: The reason your breakers don't trip is probably because you don't use more than 20 amps per circuit.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question but I understand why some people did and I think the wording of the top line needs to be improved.  It's not useful as it stands.  The more detailed explanation reveals an excellent question.

Comment: If you want to really cheese off your landlord, you might consider calling a city building/electrical inspector to come have a look. These things will be flagged and the landlord will have to fix them. **However**, he will be _most_ unhappy with you and will make your life, for the length of your lease, absolutely miserable. I'd plan on moving at the end of the lease. Of course, you may have a really good landlord who just didn't know about these violations, only you can gauge that.

Comment: You could choose to call the inspectors right at the end of your lease if you expect your landlord to be slime...or call them now and see about breaking the lease when the occupancy permit is revoked until the work is completed, leaving you without a house.

Comment: It's derated because installation is concealed and damage is almost undetectable after install.  Most editions of the NEC show #14 NM as at least 20A wire (1979 build probably predates NM-B so probably 20A 75°C, not 25A 90°C  modern NM-B). One reason NM is derated providing for damage that may not exist in your situation. An equal sized nick is a larger percentage of the wire if the initial size is smaller. Also it's likely breakers were swapped after build, and damage is cumulative, so you really have no idea how long it has been exposed.

Comment: @jay613, you can always make edits to a question.  The edits are voted on before they go live so feel free to reword without changing the point of the question.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I know I can make edits (in fact I think I can do it without voting) but I thought it better to coach a new user to ask a better question.

Answer (score 4):

If consuming 20 amps through 14AWG wire would consistently and instantly set aflame every house in which it was attempted, the code would not require 15A breakers for such wire.  Instead it would banish it entirely, and the whole concept of electricity for domestic use would have evolved in a very different way.  It would look nothing like it does today.

Domestic electricity is pretty safe, but there are still over 40,000 residential electrical fires [causing over 400 deaths](https://www.nfpa.org//-/media/Files/News-and-Research/Fire-statistics-and-reports/US-Fire-Problem/Fire-causes/osHomeElectricalFires.pdf) annually in the USA.  The safe practice of installing electrical infrastructure is constantly evolving and improving.  A lot of the practices and code requirements are designed to protect life in rare or edge cases.   To reduce this number from 400 to as close to zero as can be.  We learn and we improve.

We do a lot better than to prevent only the worst and most obvious problems.  The requirement to protect 14AWG wire with a 15A fuse is because there have been some fires, and some deaths, that could have been prevented that way.   Hopefully, in your home, the circumstances that led to those deaths will not be reproduced.  That it hasn't happened *yet* is not an indictment of the code requirement!

Comment: Good answer, and I'll add that pulling more that 15A is hard to do because most appliances use much less than that.  Unless you are running multiple space heaters or other electric heating device, you're not going to go over 15A.  Even in a wood shop, you're normally using one tool at a time (DIY shop, one man).

Comment: While I understand that I generally only use 1 tool at a time. My concern (which is why I included it specifically in the question) is the washer and dryer on same circuit and running at same time which is common. (BTW dust collector has to run at same time as any other tool I have connected)

Comment: There are layers of protection.  Washer and gas dryer pull maybe 20 to 25 amps if they both use peak power simultaneously, for seconds or minutes at a time.  Maybe this happens sometimes.  Maybe your wires start to warm up.   Now you have one less layer of protection.  How many layers have to peel back before a fire starts?  *Not just 1*.  That is my point.

Comment: I was on a plane where the pilot announced an emergency because the passenger emergency oxygen pressure sensor had failed.  Note, there was nothing wrong with the plane.  There was nothing even wrong with the passenger emergency oxygen.  He just lost the ability to know if something wrong developed with it.  So we descended immediately and abruptly to 10,000 feet and landed at the nearest airport.  Layers of safety is why there aren't more deaths in the air.  And that level of care is why you don't hear about more home electrical fires.